# Mysql get values that only occur once

Tags: mysql

I am trying to find the first and last names of applicants who submitted exactly one application. anumber being the application number.

my relevant tables:

```
    APPLICANT (anumber, lname, fname)
    APPLIES (anumber, pnumber)
```

what I have:

```
    SELECT lname, fname FROM (SELECT COUNT(anumber) 
    AS count FROM APPLIES GROUP BY anumber HAVING (count = 1)) AS x;
```

I am new to MySQL and don't know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that anumber is the applicant ID, not the application ID. Most applications doesn't have a first & last name.

So it would be:

```
SELECT lname, fname  
FROM applicant  
inner join (select anumber, count(pnumber) from applies group by anumber having count(pnumber)=1) as x  
ON applicant.anumber = x.anumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as the one above, however it uses a nested if statement instead, depending on what is required.

SELECT fname, lname
FROM APPLICANT
WHERE anumber IN (
   SELECT anumber
   FROM APPLIES
   GROUP BY anumber
   HAVING count(pnumber) = 1);